# Visual studio 2010 Publish / web deploy issues

Tags: visual-studio, iis-7, msdeploy, web-deployment, webdeploy

I'm using Publish/Web Deploy to deploy an asp.net aplication from Visual studio 2010. It works perfect, but there is a problem. If the new release is not working as expected, the old version is already replaced by the new one and there is no easy way to roll back to the working version. How is this best solved? I wish it was possible to keep the old version on the server so I could just switch back if needed.

Answer (score 3):

With WebDeploy there is no built in rollback feature, so once you've deployed that's it.

There's a number of hand rolled strategies you could put in place, for example:

**Limited Access e.g. Shared Hosting:**

Where you don't have full access to the machine -

1. Backup the live site beforehand by downloading it.
2. Keep copies of what you deployed so you can push the previous version should something break

**Full Access:**

Maintain two sets of folders for the application and map your site to one or other of these folders. When you come to deploy switch the IIS site's physical path to the *other* folder then deploy. If the site fails then just knock the site back to the original folder. Each successful deploy would alternate between these two folders.

For stuff like user uploaded content you'd need to map virtual directories to a place on the file system that's always the same place because you don't want to be copying these around each time.

You're not the only one who has encountered these issues. Have a look at this article by Rob Conery and his observations about the state of affairs regarding ASP.NET deployment.

> [ASP.NET Deployment Needs To Be Fixed](http://wekeroad.com/post/4373719917/aspnet-deployment-needs-to-be-fixed)
>
> [Getting Constructive On ASP.NET Deployment](http://wekeroad.com/post/4456244952/getting-constructive-on-aspnet-deployment)

Comment: Thank you. This is like I did it before (when deploying manually). I was hoping there was a way to automate the create backup/copy - step.

Comment: @rgull - unless you script the whole build and deploy then there isn't anything built-in to give you instant rollback capability.

Answer (score 0):

Using some form of Source Control would be another alternative.  We use subversion, so if the publish goes bad, we can just update back to the last-good revision, and publish that.  Even if you're the only developer, using source control can be very useful.